# VBA - MS Word - how to detect that there is not document open or created?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In MS Word I need to detect if there is any document open or none document is open. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more information would be helpful but generally in VBA you can use: `Application.Documents.Count`

Although I suspect that this won't help you and perhaps what you are more interested in is `application.ProtectedViewWindows.count`